# How do I remove space, %20, double dashes and other characters in PHP

Tags: php, youtube, content-management-system

I have videosearchXL script (YouTube CMS PHP script). In that script, the URLs are not search-engine friendly and have a very large mess like %20, double and even triple dashes, (, %7 and some other characters. I know nothing about PHP but looking on my codes I can understand that following codes are responsible for generating URLs.

```
<? include ('siteconfig.php'); 
function cano($s){
$s = str_replace(" ", "-", $s);
$s = strip_tags($s);
$s = strtolower($s);
return $s;
}
$link = $_GET['link'];
$link = explode("/", $link);
{include("apis/youtube/video.php");}
?>
```

So please help me to remove these spaces and unusual characters. I also used the .htaccess method but that did not work for me.

Comment: `%20` is an encoded space.  It has to be there; the URL won't work without it.  The way you solve the problem is by not presenting the code with strings that have spaces in them in the first place.

Comment: I want to replace %20 with dash (-).